# SpringBoot Not Picking Up Custom Converter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am running a Spring Data Rest application based off of Spring Boot 2.1.6 and want to register a custom converter to convert a string to an object:

`curl http://localhost:8082/dataPoints/search/findByTrackable\?trackable\=http://localhost:8081/trackables/23`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface DataPointRepo extends CrudRepository<DataPoint<?>, Long> {
    public Set<DataPoint<?>> findByTrackable(Trackable trackable);  
}
```

Trackable is not actually a persistent entity in this application but a remote resource, as you can see by the two different port numbers used in the curl command.

All I want to store locally is the ID of the trackable resource but I want findByTrackable to work with a URL rather than the ID value.

I created this converter only to see that it gets invoked:

```
@Component
public class UrlToTrackableConverter implements Converter<String, Trackable> {

    @Override
    public Trackable convert(String source) {
        System.out.println("############################");
        System.out.println("Hell Yeah");
        return null;
    }

}
```

As far as I understand, annotating the class with @Component and implementing the Converter interface should register the converter, but instead I get this when I run the Curl as above:

https://pastebin.com/Lsctw6uf

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell Spring about this new converter by adding the `UrlToTrackableConverter` to the `FormatterRegistry`.

This can be done by implementing the `WebMvcConfigurer` and overriding `addFormatters()` method:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new UrlToTrackableConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the WebConfig you suggested, but still get the same error message.

Comment: return `Trackable` from `findByTrackable`.

Comment: But that's in the DataPointRepo. Returning Trackable here doesn't seem to make much sense, does it? I wand to find all DataPoints that reference that Trackable.

Comment: Question: As you said you are using spring boot, is `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is turned on?

Comment: Also, what is your repository configuration? are you using `@RepositoryRestController` for your controller method?

Comment: What is the caller method looks like? can you show it?

Comment: There is not caller method. I added the full repository above, but it's just an interface tat gets exported by SDR. I have SpringBootApplication which includes EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: @rimonmostafiz actually just adding a `@Component` on the custom converter class is enough in a spring boot app. No need to add it explicitly to the FormatterRegistry.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's a deprecated solution:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(new UrlToTrackableConverter());
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }

}
```

Since RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, this is not the ideal solution but a working one. If anyone knows how to do this properly, please let me know.